# Origin of Vasavi Sakti

Tags: indra, karna

It is well known that Indra had gifted the Vasavi Sakti weapon to Karna in return of the Kavash and Kundal.

But, why is that weapon so powerful? What is the origin of Vasavi Sakti??

Comment: I think vasavi shakti has something to do with the 8 Vasus  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasu So in a way this power allows its user to control elements related to vasus.

Comment: @Yoigi: But, please cite some references

Comment: Sir this comment is my instinct about Vasva power not the complete answer. I don't have any authentic references to cite here, that is why I presented it as comment not as an answer.

Comment: @Yogi I think the term "Vasavi Shakti" has to do with the fact that Vasava is a name of Indra.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yeah that may be the case, but the question is now about authenticity and proof of our calims.

Comment: @All: So, let us collectively try to find out some references.....actually, this is a mystery; I have found no reference to the weapon, which is so powerful....

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Can you help me to understand the origin of the Vasavi Sakti weapon. See, this weapon is not found to be mentioned in the Ramyana, or other puranas. How did Indra get this weapon?

Comment: I think "Vasavi Shakti" is just another name for the Indrastra; in fact I don't think the term "Vasavi Shakti" is ever used in the Mahabharata.  And I think the Indrastra is mentioned in plenty of other scriptures, like in the Ramayana during Lakshmana's battle with Indrajit.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Maybe you are right. But, I do not understand that why that weapon was regarded as very powerful. Even, Krishna was afraid; and thus kept away from Karna most of the time.